# DBF viewer for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I need to open dbf files on my Ubuntu 15 and as I found LibreOffice can does this. But I'm getting

> General Error. General input/output error.

Is there ANY tool or built-in some software tool that can help me?

Comment: We do not care if it opens on Windows.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yeah, and that's will make me answering such questions as "Did you try to open it in some other system/software?"

Comment: Even if that is a valid question it will be *Ubuntu* only. And we do not expect a user to have Windows installed ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind It actually shows that the file is (likely) valid.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [LibreOffice Wiki](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Importing_and_Exporting_dBASE_Files) you should be able to open `.dbf` files with LibreOffice Base.

If you still encounter this problem, reinstall LibreOffice:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

---

You can also use `dbview` to open `.dbf` files (which may be harder to use than LibreOffice Base):

```
sudo apt-get install dbview
```

Refer to the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/dbview.1.html) for more information on `dbview`.

Comment: Great! I guess I didn't have LibreOffice Base and reinstallation bring it) Also dbview is a good console (as I got it right) app that can make preview dbf file easily. Thank you.

Comment: As LibreOffice Base is not installed by default in Ubuntu, you might want to start by checking that it actually is.

Answer (score 5):

For very simple editing of small .dbf files, you can also use [GTK DBF Editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkdbfeditor)

To install it in Ubuntu 12.04, I first needed to install this dependency:

```
sudo apt-get install libglade2-0:i386
```

Then I could install the downloaded .deb file with

```
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/gtkdbfeditor_1.0.4-7_i386.deb
```

**Update:**

In Ubuntu 16.04, with the default install of LibreOffice, I had to also

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-base
```

Then, .dbf files can be opened in LibreOffice Calc, and also saved as .dbf.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the best way to deal with .dbf files is to use PHP to convert them to .csv files:

```
<?php

set_time_limit( 24192000 );
ini_set( 'memory_limit', '-1' );

$files = glob( '/media/d/Data2/files/*.DBF' );
foreach( $files as $file )
{
    echo "Processing: $file\n";
    $fileParts = explode( '/', $file );
    $endPart = $fileParts[key( array_slice( $fileParts, -1, 1, true ) )];
    $csvFile = preg_replace( '~\.[a-z]+$~i', '.csv', $endPart );

    if( !$dbf = dbase_open( $file, 0 ) ) die( "Could not connect to: $file" );
    $num_rec = dbase_numrecords( $dbf );
    $num_fields = dbase_numfields( $dbf );

    $fields = array();
    $out = '';

    for( $i = 1; $i <= $num_rec; $i++ )
    {
        $row = @dbase_get_record_with_names( $dbf, $i );
        $firstKey = key( array_slice( $row, 0, 1, true ) );
        foreach( $row as $key => $val )
        {
            if( $key == 'deleted' ) continue;
            if( $firstKey != $key ) $out .= ';';
            $out .= trim( $val );
        }
        $out .= "\n";
    }

    file_put_contents( $csvFile, $out );
}

?>
```

Then use MySQL to import the CSV:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/media/d/Data2/files/ZACATECAS.csv" INTO TABLE tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```